# Remove last characters of string if string starts with pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have a column of strings that I would like to remove everything after the last '.' like so:

```
ENST00000338167.9
ABCDE.42927.6
ENST00000265393.10
ABCDE.43577.3
ENST00000370826.3
```

I would like to replace remove the '.' and everything after for the 'ENST' entries only
eg:

```
ENST00000338167
ABCDE.42927.6
ENST00000265393
ABCDE.43577.3
ENST00000370826
```

I can do

```
function(x) sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", x)
```

if I try

```
function(x) sub("ENST*\\.[^.]*$", "", x)
```

this isn't quite working and I don't fully understand the regex commands.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you haven't accepted any answer (including this) to all your questions till now. Please consider accepting one of the answer by clicking on check mark next to vote button. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use combination of `ifelse`, `grepl` and `sub`. We first check if the string consists of "ENST" string and if it does then remove everything after "." using `sub`.

```
ifelse(grepl("^ENST", x), sub("\\..*", "", x), x)

#[1] "ENST00000338167" "ABCDE.42927.6"   "ENST00000265393" "ABCDE.43577.3"  
#[5] "ENST00000370826"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("ENST00000338167.9","ABCDE.42927.6","ENST00000265393.10",
       "ABCDE.43577.3","ENST00000370826.3")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a capture group inside a single `gsub` call

```
gsub("(^ENST\\d+)\\.\\d+", "\\1", df[, 1])
#[1] "ENST00000338167" "ABCDE.42927.6"   "ENST00000265393" "ABCDE.43577.3"
#[5] "ENST00000370826"
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ENST00000338167.9
ABCDE.42927.6
ENST00000265393.10
ABCDE.43577.3
ENST00000370826.3", header = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` to specify the logical condition in `i` while updating the `j`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grepl("^ENST", Col1), Col1 := sub("\\.[^.]+$", "", Col1)]
df
#             Col1
#1: ENST00000338167
#2:   ABCDE.42927.6
#3: ENST00000265393
#4:   ABCDE.43577.3
#5: ENST00000370826
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("ENST00000338167.9", "ABCDE.42927.6", 
"ENST00000265393.10", "ABCDE.43577.3", "ENST00000370826.3")), row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `startsWith` and `sub` combination:

Data:

```
 df=read.table(text="ENST00000338167.9
  ABCDE.42927.6
  ENST00000265393.10
  ABCDE.43577.3
  ENST00000370826.3",header=F)


# if string starts with ENST then remove everything after . (dot) in the 
#  string else print the string as it is.
  ifelse(startsWith(as.character(df[,1]),"ENST"),sub("*\\..*", "", df$V1),
      as.character(df[,1]))
```

Output:

```
[1] "ENST00000338167" "ABCDE.42927.6"   "ENST00000265393" "ABCDE.43577.3"   "ENST00000370826"
```